# Python OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied | fd, addr = self._accept()

Tags: python, windows, sockets, server, client

I am attempting to make a simple client and server in Python. The server seems to be completely fine but the client throws the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Client.py", line 6, in <module>
    connection, address = client.accept()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 292, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

Here is the server code:

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((socket.gethostname(), 8080))
server.listen(5)

while True:
    connection, address = server.accept()
    fromClient = ''

    while True:
        data = connection.recv(2048)
        if not data:
            break
        fromClient = fromClient + data
        print(fromClient)
        connection.send(str.encode('yo'))
    connection.close()
    print('client disconnected')
```

Here is the client code:

```
import time
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((socket.gethostname(), 8080))
client.settimeout(3)
time.sleep(3)
#client.send(str.encode('client'))
connection, address = client.accept()
fromServer = client.recv(2048)
fromServer = fromServer.decode('utf-8')
client.close()
print(fromServer)
```

The server binds to the ip and port so they are OK, but the client errors out when attempting the same thing. Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?

I have also tried sleeping before the client.accept() line and this has not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking `accept` method on client socket which is not set to passive mode by calling `listen`. Moreover, the socket is already in connected state (`connect` is called prior), now you cant expect your socket to listen and accept connections. But the long story short, just remove the code where you called `accept` in client and it runs fine.

Comment: @mwolfe See how should you be accepting answers and what comments you need to post [accepting-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Since you are new to stackoverflow community give a refresh to that link